# Radiobutton on selection do a function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have two radio buttons. If the user chose one of them i would like my code to execute one particular function. I need to get the value from the radio button selection and push it to my function on the server-side as "valueButton". Guess i need a function on the client-side, but how should that look?

**The buttons (client-side):**

```
 <div>
          <input type="radio" name="origin" id="radio-origin-1" value="ID1">
          <label for="radio-origin-auto">Grupp 1</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="radio" name="origin" id="radio-origin-2" value="ID2">
          <label for="radio-origin-en">Grupp 2</label>
        </div>
```

**The functions (server-side):**

```
function dataSelect(valueButton){

   if (valueButton == "ID1") {
    ID1(); }
  else if (valueButton == "ID2") {
    ID2(); }
   }

function ID1(){
   MailApp.sendEmail("test.acc@outlook.com", "subjects", GetDataFromSpreadsheet());}

function ID2(){
   MailApp.sendEmail("test.acc2@outlook.com", "subjects", GetDataFromSpreadsheet());}
```

Comment: i would use an ajax request that fires everytime a radio-button has been changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML Code**

```
 <div>
 <input type="radio" name="origin" id="radio-origin-1" value="ID1" onChange="dataSelect(this.value);">
 <label for="radio-origin-auto">Grupp 1</label>
 </div>
 <div>
 <input type="radio" name="origin" id="radio-origin-2" value="ID2" onChange="dataSelect(this.value);">
 <label for="radio-origin-en">Grupp 2</label>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hi Chris, sorry putting onChange="dataSelect(this.value);"> just makes it a string, what should i do with it?

Comment: @user3432918 I don't understand what you are saying, but I'll give it a try.    
`document.getElementById("radio-origin-1").onchange = function() {
  dataSelect("ID1");
}    
document.getElementById("radio-origin-2").onchange = function() {
  dataSelect("ID2");
}`    
Try putting this in your Javascript code. Hope it helps.

Comment: @user3432918 Or if you are asking how the code works, well, basically when any radio button is selected, the value of the radio button that has been selected will be used as the argument of the `dataSelect();` function.  
  
So for example, if the second radio button is selected, the value of the second radio button (which is ID2) will be used as the argument of the `dataSelect();` function, so the code `dataSelect("ID2");" will run.  
  
Hope that helps too.